# How to automatically start Azure WebJob with TimeTrigger after recycle/restart WebApp

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am using a WebJob in an Azure WebApp. The job executes a method:

```
public static void ProcessQueue(
            [TimerTrigger("00:02:00")] TimerInfo timerInfo,
            [Queue("queue")] CloudQueue queue,
            [Table("processing")] CloudTable processingTable,
            TextWriter log)
{
    // do sth...
}
```

The `TimeTrigger` option came from [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions).

I set the WebApp to run in ["always on" mode](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/).

But if I am doing a restart or change a application setting the WebApp does possibly, internally make a recycle? I think.

Because after this I am getting the following error:

> [11/10/2016 08:22:24 > 36d12e: SYS ERR ] WebJob run failed due to: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>      at Kudu.Core.Jobs.BaseJobRunner.RunJobInstance(JobBase job, IJobLogger logger, String runId, String trigger, ITracer tracer, Int32 port)
>      at Kudu.Core.Jobs.TriggeredJobRunner.<>c__DisplayClass10_1.b__0(Object _)

So I tried to set a schedule on the WebJob and I also tried to paste a CRON schedule in the directory but nothing helped my out to bring the job to "running" after a reset/recycle.

**Update 1**
The content of my exe (`Main()`)

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Verbose;
config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = 10;
config.UseCore();
config.UseTimers();
var host = new JobHost(config);
host.RunAndBlock();
```

**Update 2**
If I deploy as continous manually in Azure Portal everything is running as expected (Thanks mathewc). But this is a manually step ;). I am in a DevOps scenario everything will be build, created and deployed by the **Visual Studio Team Services** and there you cannot set any option to deploy the **job as continous**.

Comment: Can you also share your exe startup code, so I can see if you're starting the WebJobs SDK JobHost correctly?

Comment: @mathewc: Added as Update1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the call stack you've shown, it looks like you may have incorrectly deployed your job as a **triggered** rather than **continuous** WebJob? When using the WebJobs SDK, you should deploy your WebJobs as continuous as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/).

Once running in continuous mode, you are correct that if you change an app setting or otherwise cause a restart, your WebJobs will also restart. However the internal scheduler for TimerTrigger will ensure the job continues to run on schedule when it comes back up.

Comment: See [this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/05/18/deploying-and-schedule-azure-webjobs-from-vsts-to-azure-web-app-with-bonus-cron-scheduling/) for details on setting up automatic VSTS deployment. That page deploys an OnDemand, but if you select Continuous, you'll get what you need.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Found this page before but isn't it strange to configure the scheduler locally in visual studio publishing and then this configuration will be used to deploy by vsts?

Comment: I pointed to that page to show how WebJob publishing works. In your case you'd be deploying a continuous WebJob, not configuring a schedule since you're using the WebJobs SDK TimerTrigger.

Comment: I found that if you deploy a scheduled job as "continuous" and the webjob is scaled out, then multiple instances of it run. This is a major inconvenience. Just be aware of this. There are workarounds to try to adjust for this using the settings.job file, but I would prefer to be able to automatically start the triggered job.